# CURL on localhost with MOD_REWRITE -> 404 (but fine in browser)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, curl, url-rewriting, localhost

I have a website hosted on my local server (http://localhost/), which uses url_rewriting.

When I access a page with the browser, no issue, it's loading.
But when I access the same url with PHP cUrl, I get a 404.

**Example:**
URL with mod_rewrite: http://localhost/site/test
Real page: http://localhost/site/test.php

Loading http://localhost/site/test from Firefox: **Working**

**Loading using cUrl:**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/site/test");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

$output -> 404 page from apache

Anybody knows why cUrl returns a 404 message?

Comment: Figure out why your webserver returns a 404 for the cURL request. Maybe the request isn't what you think it is, maybe your webserver switched on some optional header (like User-Agent). Add a `RewriteRule` that acts like a catch-all, log the request and compare.

Comment: What are your RewriteRules?  Are you doing an external redirect or internal rewrite?  If the former you would need to include the follow option in your curl config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this has nothing to do with mod_rewrite.
One of the directory in the URL had a space in it, that I was not encoding when calling the cUrl function.
Once replaced all space by %20, everything worked fine.

Subject closed.